# Removing button after updating database values

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page where users can view the leave applications they submitted and they can also cancel the application, here's what it looks like:
[image: View application page]

I wanted to get rid of the cancel button after it was cancelled or after it was clicked. So I added a remove button script in the execution code. Apparently, it was wrong. Everything worked fine until I added the script in the execution code.

Here's my form:

**HTML+PHP**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>My Leaves</h3>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            <?php
                include ('database.php');
                $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT leaves.* FROM leaves INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = leaves.user_id WHERE employee.username = '".$_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]."'");
                $result ->execute();
                for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['firstname']." " .$row_message['lastname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['type']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="update-leave-status-emp.php">
                            <input type="hidden" name="leaveno" value="<?php echo $row_message['leaveno']; ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Cancelled" class="removebtn" name="cancelled"></input>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
            </table>
            <a href="employee_panel.php">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Execution Code:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['cancelled'])){
        $msg = "Cancelled";
        $status=$_POST['cancelled'];
        echo "<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".removebtn").click(function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
        </script>";
    }
    $leaveno=$_POST['leaveno'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'companydb');
    $sql = "UPDATE leaves SET status = '$status' WHERE leaveno = '$leaveno'";
    if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))header("refresh:1; url=view-leave-emp.php?msg=$msg");
    else var_dump(mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

PS: I know my codes are vulnerable to injections, I will change it eventually, for now, I have to figure this out.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: You would need Javascript for that since you can't use PHP to alter an allready rendered page. Also, you code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. Be careful.

Comment: @tadman I'm aware of that, I will change it once I get to fix this problem.

Comment: Fix it now when you write it. Coding like this is completely reckless and must be avoided at all costs. If you forget, which is bound to happen eventually if you make it a habit to do security later on as an after-thought, you *will* get burned. Doing it correctly is not only safe, it saves you a ton of time trying to track down annoying and entirely preventable bugs that relate to escaping issues.

Comment: What are the possible values of status field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosed cancelled button in an if statement that if the record is marked cancelled the button won't be shown anymore.

**You can try this updated code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>My Leaves</h3>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>From</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Reason</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            <?php
                include ('database.php');
                $result = $database->prepare ("SELECT leaves.* FROM leaves INNER JOIN employee ON employee.id = leaves.user_id WHERE employee.username = '".$_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"]."'");
                $result ->execute();
                for ($count=0; $row_message = $result ->fetch(); $count++){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['firstname']." " .$row_message['lastname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['phone']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['email']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['fromdate']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['todate']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['reason']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['type']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_message['status']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="update-leave-status-emp.php">
                            <input type="hidden" name="leaveno" value="<?php echo $row_message['leaveno']; ?>" />
                          <?php if( $row_message['status'] != "Cancelled" ) {
                            <input type="submit" value="Cancelled" class="removebtn" name="cancelled"></input>
                          <?php } ?>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php }?>
            </table>
            <a href="employee_panel.php">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i> Back</button>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Btw, your code is vulnerable to sql injections. You may wanna fix your prepared statements as well to prevent that.